# Render login Form

Tags: forms, 8, users, theming

I would like to call the user login form in my theme but I can't.

In Drupal 7 I did this.

```
$elements = drupal_get_form("user_login"); 
$form = drupal_render($elements);    
echo utf8_decode($form);
```

How I can do this with Drupal 8?

I tried this.

```
Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class)
```

How do I render this?

With the following code, I can show the login form, but I can't log in with it. What should I add to make it work?

```
$form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class) ; 
$render = Drupal::service('renderer');
$render->renderPlain($form);
```

Comment: `drupal_render` is still available in Drupal 8, you should use that

Comment: The problem's with drupal_render it's they are Deprecated with drupal 8. What should be done to can use RendererInterface in my theme ?

Comment: Oops you're right, sorry. So the deprecation notice has the answer: _Use the 'renderer' service instead._

Comment: tank's many.
Wenn I found How to check the login I put this question as answered. (now wenn I test to log I have this in my url mysitename/cms/system/403?destination=/cms/admin/modules and I return in my login page )

Comment: Finally I don't was find the possibility to log in with this form beacause the login doesn't works. I have found a other solution.

The login works perfectly with bartik theme , I changed the theme to login page to bartik. They are a little diy but but it works. 

I do not close the question because I'm curious how to solve the problem in a more clean

Answer (score 9):

The code seems to be working fine. If it doesn't work for some reason, make sure that there is nothing else in the theme or modules that might interfere with this.

Here's how to provide a rendered login form through preprocess function. (This code would go to `YOUR_THEME.theme` file.)

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // You will most likely want to show and render the form for anonymous users.
  $login_form = FALSE;
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    $login_form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class);
  }
  $variables['login_form'] = $login_form;
}
```

Then in the page.html.twig template, you can render it (and use it) with the following code.

```
{{ login_form }}
```

Comment: You should use the User method isAnonymous() instead of testing the ID (it's basically the same, but more readable I think). And the ::class PHP property return the class name and namespace of a class in string, witch is exactly the class full name you define : then use directly 'Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm' as a string.

Comment: It's better to not render the form before passing it to the template, so the code could read: $variables['login_form'] = $form; and you can skip the 2 lines around rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of <del>`drupal_render()`</del> which is deprecated in Drupal 8, e.g.

```
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($form);
```

Answer (score 1):

In D8 you create render Arrays in Controllers (extends Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase). For your need you could do it like with the following code.

```
$fb = $this->formBuilder();
return $fb->getForm("Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm");
```

Comment: what does $this refer to?!

Comment: to any class that inherits from ControllerBase